# How do you know how many close votes are on a question?

Tags: feature-request, support

How do I know how many close votes there are for a question I asked?

Update:

I still think it would be nice to see how many votes there are to close your question when you don't have enough rep. At least you have an idea about if you are asking good questions or not, becuase I sure don't get that much upvoting on my questions for whatever the reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have > 3000 rep, it will tell you in parentheses. Then, you can click the close link to get the actual number (in parens) with each reason.

On your own question, though, you need > 250 rep to vote to close. Ironic, eh?

Assuming you're talking about [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297550/direction-on-programming-language-platform-that-my-teenager-should-go-to-next). Somebody voted to close as Too Localized. Why? I have no bloody clue.

Comment: That sucks that as the question asker I can't even see how many close votes there are.

Comment: What difference does it make, though? If it's going to get closed it will get closed regardless

Comment: I was just curious because someone commented on my SO question "Boo to the close-voter! Boo, I say!" so I was like huh!

Comment: @Eric, yes I am talking about that question, I still don't see any option that allows me to vote to close my own question though?

Comment: Under the question, you don't have `edit | close | delete`?

Comment: @Eric, I have " edit | rollback | delete | flag " on that particular question

Comment: @Breadtruck: 250 rep gets you `close` on your own questions.

Answer (score 1):

On every question there is a little menu where the flag and edit buttons are. The more rep you have, the more options you see next to it. At 3,000 rep, you can see the 'Close' menu which will say next to it how many votes are currently in place to close or reopen the question.

Also, if it is your question, you can see the same menu.

Comment: I guess I will never see those!!